# The site says :"Restricted files" While loging in to phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04, webmin

I am trying to log in to the `phpMyadmin` using `ipaddress`. before i access the login page of phpMyadmin i get a restriction asking me to enter username and password. I know the credentials for phpMyAdmin but I forgot the credentials to server password. I cannot change or see what my server password is. I am using ubuntu server with `Webmin`.

Is it possible to remove this login criteria if I want to log into the phpmyadmin.

Two questions:

- how to change or view previous password and username
- how to remove this restriction if I want to access the phpMyadmin
  remotely

Comment: Additionally: I tried to type in my root password, root as username

Comment: I would like to acknowledge that i am using firefox web browser

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my local server.

In my case the solution was to configure the htpasswd file.

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.phpmyadmin.htpasswd username
```

Change "username" to the user you want to use for authentication. 
Then it ask for a password, give one you like.

A good tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04